# How long overnight oats are safe/ok to eat

Tags: food-safety, storage-method

So I forgot my bowl of oats in the fridge and it has been 15 hours, I can either throw them away and make another bowl but I wanted to ask if it is safe to consume a bowl of oats that have been left in the fridge for 15 hours?

Answer (score 2):

What would make them unsafe? Oats are shelf stable.  Milk is refrigerator stable for quite some time.

Comment: Oats are shelf-stable because they're dry. So that really doesn't apply anymore. However, basically everything remains safe in the fridge for at least a few days — 15 hours is no problem.

Comment: @derobert exactly...key is in the refrigerator...if significant time between soaking and refrigeration occurred...all bets are off and that would not be a safe practice.

Answer (score 0):

Flapjacks can (and should) be refrigerated after baking, so it stands to reason that oats should be fine in the fridge.